# Confusion with fwrite in VC2012

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, fwrite

I need to write some binary data into file. The format is `uint64_t`.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <assert.h>
  typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;

  int main()
  {
    FILE * file = fopen("data","w");assert(file);
    uint64_t a[]={16000550, 1051320,14456018, 4743184,11840752 ,4225032,\
                      13642264,6059108,563784 ,11823354,3989084 ,15759410,\
                      13413018 ,1582802,1574952 ,1635384,1102996 ,10511428,\
                      10239562 ,9472574,2641952 ,1350256,3432142 ,9920,11573360,\
                      12121180,10255874 ,3198684,7628524,16522766,12908660,\
                      2681374,9482820 ,6354462,15230702 ,16255676,5813862, \
                      8174782,7642752,7362790,6089340 ,803928,2669686 ,4225032,\
                      7603956 ,16551562,15734364 ,14424308,12060282 ,572450,\
                      18432 ,10276902,8134910 ,10749010,14166126 ,1636942,\
                      5295788 ,12342876,2151156 ,12322948};
     for(int i=0;i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(uint64_t);i++)
     {
    fwrite((char*)&a[i],sizeof(uint64_t),1,file);
     }
         fclose(file);
  }
```

I found the output doesn't satisfy my expectation only when the size of array is large, so I give 60 `uint64_t`s in my example.

In test, I found it will output `0000 fe20 7c00 0000` for `8134910`. Also, some others errors exists in it. In GCC, it works well and in VS2012, it works bad.

Comment: Does it change if you force the file to binary mode `fopen("data","wb")` ?

Comment: @RogerRowland It works well with your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your feedback in comments, the reason it's different in VS2012 is because the file has been opened by defualt in "text" mode. In this mode, each `\n` when written will be expanded to `\r\n`, which will corrupt your data.

The solution is to explicitly open the file in binary mode:

```
FILE * file = fopen("data","wb")
```

Quoting from MSDN regarding the **t** and **b** characters that may be appended to the *mode*:

> **t**
>
> Open in text (translated) mode. In this mode, CTRL+Z is interpreted
>   as an EOF character on input. In files that are opened for
>   reading/writing by using "**a+**", **fopen** checks for a CTRL+Z at the end of
>   the file and removes it, if possible. This is done because using **fseek**
>   and **ftell** to move within a file that ends with CTRL+Z may cause **fseek**
>   to behave incorrectly near the end of the file.
>
> In text mode, carriage return–linefeed combinations are translated
>   into single linefeeds on input, and linefeed characters are translated
>   to carriage return–linefeed combinations on output. When a Unicode
>   stream-I/O function operates in text mode (the default), the source or
>   destination stream is assumed to be a sequence of multibyte
>   characters. Therefore, the Unicode stream-input functions convert
>   multibyte characters to wide characters (as if by a call to the **mbtowc**
>   function). For the same reason, the Unicode stream-output functions
>   convert wide characters to multibyte characters (as if by a call to
>   the **wctomb** function).
>
> **b**
>
> Open in binary (untranslated) mode; translations involving
>   carriage-return and linefeed characters are suppressed.
>
> If **t** or **b** is not given in mode, the default translation mode is
>   defined by the global variable `_fmode`.

The MSDN documentation for `_fmode` says:

> The default setting of `_fmode` is **_O_TEXT** for text-mode
>   translation. **_O_BINARY** is the setting for binary mode.